# How do I update a html element with response from Ajax JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an java application running, with a REST @POST endpoint, which takes an SQL query, and returns the result in a csv format.

The endpoint works, I can get the correct results via Curl and Postman.

Now, I am trying to call this endpoint via javascript, and to update a HTML value with the response. But have no experience with js.

This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Making A POST</h1>

<p id="demo">Change this text.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
     $.post("http://localhost:4567/query/sql/csv",
    "SELECT * FROM testTable",
    function(data,status){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $result;
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is successfully making the POST request, can see from the application console. But it is not changing the HTML element with the response:
`<p id="demo">Change this text.</p>`

Comment: Downvoting simply due to the ajax call passing SQL.  This is a major security flaw.

Comment: `$result`? What is that?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you're using a var that is undefined: `$result`
I think you wanted to use `data` instead.
Like this: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;`

Comment: My mistake, result is from old variable. I still have the same issue with `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;`

Comment: data is null or something? what does data contain?

Comment: `Change this text.` is not changing at all. I think this function is not being executed: `function(data,status){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Code works.
The issue was Chrome and Internet Explorer blocking the script.